# How to remove trailing zeros using pandas only if the column's dtype is numeric?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe like this,

```
A        |  B
2.000000 | "hello 1.0"
3.00000  | "mellow"
         | "trello 9.0 elo"
4.0      | "cello 3.00"
```

How can I get the output like this,

```
A   |  B
2   | "hello 1.0"
3   | "mellow"
    | "trello 9.0 elo"
4   | "cello 3.00"
```

I want to convert all columns dtypes to string; however, I want to be able to remove the trailing zeros only if the column's dtype is numeric.

There was one solution where you could use lambda function but I do not exactly remember the format.

So far I have this,

```
df[base_column].astype(str).str.replace(‘.0’, ‘ ‘).replace('nan', np.nan).replace('None', np.nan)
```

but this code converts column B also from hello 1.0 to hello 1

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I guess reason for `.0` values are missing values, so here is possible use [`integer_na`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].astype('Int64')
```

If need replace all numeric to strings with removed trailing `.0` use:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(str).replace('\.0','',regex=True).replace(['nan','None'], np.nan)
```

Comment: thanks, what if i want to convert all column's dtypes to string but if the dtype is numeric just remove the trailing zeros

Comment: thanks, but this would consume a lot more time to execute if the dataset is huge..I was looking something with lambda function to convert the column into 'int32' should the dtype is numeric

Comment: @leope - Sorry, not understand.

Comment: won't you have to search throughout the dataset to convert from .0 to '' with your current answer? I want to remove the trailing zero only if the dtype is numeric..

Comment: @leope - yes, exactly this do my answer. It filter only numeric columns to `cols` varaiable and convert to strings and remove `.0 only for numeric columns`

Comment: @leope - there is not `df = df.astype()` - processing al columns, but `df[cols] = df[cols].astype`

Comment: what about other columns that I want to convert to string? Ideally would want a function that would convert all columns to string datatype but only remove the trailing zero should the datatype of a column is numeric, for instance, please check my question i edited again for another case

Comment: @royalewithcheese - First question is if check `cols = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns` and `print (cols)` it return numeric columns? Because if different length of `0` after `.` it means no numeric column, but string. Second in my answer I seelct only numeric columns, convert to strings. Strings columns are not selected, so no touched. In my opinion here ia another problem - all columns are strings and need remove `.0`, `.000`..., right?

Answer (score 0):

this will only make only numerics as int sparing strings

```
 def func(row):
        if type(row[0])!=str:
            return (int(row[0]))
 df.apply(func,axis=1)
```