# Remove leading zeros only in case of integers datatype

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I want to remove leading zeros only in case of integer values.
I have tried the following:

```
df['col'].str.replace(r'^0+(?=[[0-9]])', '', regex=True)
```

However this does not work. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: Try: `.replace(r'^0+(?=[1-9]\d*$)', '', regex=True)`

Comment: Consider writing your comment as an answer @anubhava

Comment: Why not `df['CRITERIA_VALUE'].astype(int)`? For strings, `df['CRITERIA_VALUE'].str.replace(r'^0+(?=\d+$)', '', regex=True)` should be more reliable as it handles zero only input. Also, you mention that "this does not work" - how does it work? What is happening? What do you expect? Please share a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Check [How to remove trailing zeros using pandas only if the column's dtype is numeric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64697252/how-to-remove-trailing-zeros-using-pandas-only-if-the-columns-dtype-is-numeric), does it help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may be able to use:

```sh
df['CRITERIA_VALUE'].str.replace(r'^0+(?=[0-9]+$)', '', regex=True)
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^0+`: Match 1+ zeroes at the start.
- `(?=[0-9]+$)`: Lookahead to assert that we have 1 or more ASCII digits before end position.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IsIGt5/1)

Comment: Thanks, would you happen the solution also if i would want to remove leading zeros only in case the entire string consists of only numbers?

Comment: That's what this solution does. It removed leading zeroes only if entire string contains digits only.

Answer (score 0):

This probably works:

```
df['CRITERIA_VALUE'] = df['CRITERIA_VALUE'].str.apply(lambda x: int(x))
```